# Libre Calc spreadsheet will only store data to column IV

Tags: openoffice-calc

I have a spreadsheet with 1000 columns of data on Sheet 1 and Sheet 2. Each time I save the spreadsheet and re-open it the sheet has wiped out columns 257 onwards (i.e. column "IV" is the last column which contains data). If I enter new data into another sheet it saves it, so it's not like the spreadsheet isn't saving correctly.

Any ideas?

Using Libre Calc on Ubuntu, saving spreadsheet as **.xls**

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation of the old .xls format.  From http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_other/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-columns-in-a/5a053135-4865-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5:

> In an Excel 97-2003 format worksheet (in a .xls workbook) 256 columns (A ... IV), and in an Excel 2007-2010 format worksheet (in a .xlsx, .xlsm or .xlsb workbook) 16.384 columns (A ... XFD).

When saving as .xls, the following message appears:

[image: xls format limit]

For more than 256 columns, save as the newer .xlsx or .ods instead.